# .fadein not working on server (working locally)

Tags: javascript, jquery

FadeIn is not working when I upload it to my server, yet it is working on my local machine?

```
<script>
$("qfade").click(function () {
$("h2").fadeIn(1000);
})
</script>
```

called here

```
<li class="sup">
        <qfade><a href="#stuff">things</a></qfade>

</li>
```

You can view the whole code here: http://williamhockey.com

Comment: Why are you defining your own html element (<qfade>) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in your console.

[image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'stretch' 
                                                  http://whockey.tumblr.com/:325
```

The code is trying to call `.stretch()` on the value returned by `.contents()`:

```
$("h1").contents().stretch();
```

...but there's no such jQuery function available:

```
> $.fn.stretch
  undefined
```

Did you forget a jQuery plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using an element "qfade"? That is an invalid element. Wrap that in a `span` tag with class "qfade", then change your jquery to

```
$(".qfade").click(function () {
$("h2").fadeIn(1000);
})
```